# Avoiding downcasts in generic classes

Tags: scala

Noticing that my code was essentially iterating over a list and updating a value in a Map, I first created a trivial helper method which took a function for the transformation of the map value and return an updated map. As the program evolved, it gained a few other Map-transformation functions, so it was natural to turn it into an implicit value class that adds methods to `scala.collection.immutable.Map[A, B]`. That version works fine.

However, there's nothing about the methods that require a specific map implementation and they would seem to apply to a `scala.collection.Map[A, B]` or even a `MapLike`. So I would like it to be generic in the map type as well as the key and value types. This is where it all goes pear-shaped.

My current iteration looks like this:

```
implicit class RichMap[A, B, MapType[A, B] <: collection.Map[A, B]](
    val self: MapType[A, B]
) extends AnyVal {
  def updatedWith(k: A, f: B => B): MapType[A, B] =
    self updated (k, f(self(k)))
}
```

This code does not compile because `self updated (k, f(self(k)))` isa `scala.collection.Map[A, B]`, which is not a `MapType[A, B]`. In other words, the return type of `self.updated` is as if `self`'s type was the upper type bound rather than the actual declared type.

I can "fix" the code with a downcast:

```
def updatedWith(k: A, f: B => B): MapType[A, B] =
  self.updated(k, f(self(k))).asInstanceOf[MapType[A, B]]
```

This does not feel satisfactory because downcasting is a code smell and indicates misuse of the type system. In this particular case it would seem that the value will always be of the cast-to type, and that the whole program compiles and runs correctly with this downcast supports this view, but it still smells.

So, is there a better way to write this code to have scalac correctly infer types without using a downcast, or is this a compiler limitation and a downcast is necessary?

[Edited to add the following.]

My code which *uses* this method is somewhat more complex and messy as I'm still exploring a few ideas, but an example minimum case is the computation of a frequency distribution as a side-effect with code roughly like this:

```
var counts = Map.empty[Int, Int] withDefaultValue 0
for (item <- items) {
  // loads of other gnarly item-processing code
  counts = counts updatedWith (count, 1 + _)
}
```

There are three answers to my question at the time of writing.

One boils down to just letting `updatedWith` return a `scala.collection.Map[A, B]` anyway. Essentially, it takes my original version that accepted and returned an `immutable.Map[A, B]`, and makes the type less specific. In other words, it's still insufficiently generic and sets policy on which types the caller uses. I can certainly change the type on the `counts` declaration, but that is also a code smell to work around a library returning the wrong type, and all it really does is move the downcast into the caller's code. So I don't really like this answer at all.

The other two are variations on `CanBuildFrom` and builders in that they essentially iterate over the map to produce a modified copy. One  inlines a modified `updated` method, whereas the other calls the original `updated` and appends it to the builder and thus appears to make an extra temporary copy. Both are good answers which solve the type correctness problem, although the one that avoids an extra copy is the better of the two from a performance standpoint and I prefer it for that reason. The other is however shorter and arguably more clearly shows intent.

In the case of a hypothetical immutable Map that shares large trees in a similar vein to List, this copying would break the sharing and reduce performance and so it would be preferable to use the existing `modified` without performing copies. However, Scala's immutable maps don't appear to do this and so copying (once) seems to be the pragmatic solution that is unlikely to make any difference in practice.

Comment: "hypothetical immutable Map" Why hypothetical? HashMap has a [guaranteed](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) constant time add (which is what updated effectively is), which can be achieved only by sharing large parts of existing data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! Use [`CanBuildFrom`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/?_ga=1.8468725.1939486482.1433104516#scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom). This is how the Scala collections library infers the closest collection type to the one you want, using `CanBuildFrom` evidence. So long as you have implicit evidence of `CanBuildFrom[From, Elem, To]`, where `From` is the type of collection you're starting with, `Elem` is the type contained within the collection, and `To` is the end result you want. The `CanBuildFrom` will supply a `Builder` to which you can add elements to, and when you're done, you can call `Builder#result()` to get the completed collection of the appropriate type.

In this case:

```
From = MapType[A, B]
Elem = (A, B) // The type actually contained in maps
To = MapType[A, B]
```

Implementation:

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

implicit class RichMap[A, B, MapType[A, B] <: collection.Map[A, B]](
    val self: MapType[A, B]
) extends AnyVal {
  def updatedWith(k: A, f: B => B)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[MapType[A, B], (A, B), MapType[A, B]]): MapType[A, B] = {
    val builder = cbf()
    builder ++= self.updated(k, f(self(k)))
    builder.result()
  }
}

scala> val m = collection.concurrent.TrieMap(1 -> 2, 5 -> 3)
m: scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap[Int,Int] = TrieMap(1 -> 2, 5 -> 3)

scala> m.updatedWith(1, _ + 10)
res1: scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap[Int,Int] = TrieMap(1 -> 12, 5 -> 3)
```

Comment: Does the `builder ++= self.updated...` not cause an extra redundant copy?

Comment: Seems like it would, but manually implementing what `updated` does in an imperative way and using `builder +=` actually seems slower.

Comment: @m-z It's probably not THAT important, but this is how it is done in the library everywhere, so I'd assume `+=` should be faster. Anyway the code with `++= s.updated(...)` looks definitely much better.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that `updated` method returns `Map` class, rather than generic, so I would say you should be fine returning `Map` as well. But if you really want to return a proper type, you could have a look at implementation of `updated` in `List.updated`

I've wrote a small example. I'm not sure it covers all the cases, but it works on my tests. I also used mutable `Map`, because it was harder for me to test immutable, but I guess it can be easily converted.

```
  implicit class RichMap[A, B, MapType[x, y] <: Map[x, y]](val self: MapType[A, B]) extends AnyVal {
    import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
    def updatedWith[R >: B](k: A, f: B => R)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[MapType[A, B], (A, R), MapType[A, R]]): MapType[A, R] = {
      val b = bf(self)
      for ((key, value) <- self) {
        if (key != k) {
          b += (key -> value)
        } else {
          b += (key -> f(value))
        }
      }
      b.result()
    }
  }

  import scala.collection.immutable.{TreeMap, HashMap}

  val map1 = HashMap(1 -> "s", 2 -> "d").updatedWith(2, _.toUpperCase())  // map1 type is HashMap[Int, String]
  val map2 = TreeMap(1 -> "s", 2 -> "d").updatedWith(2, _.toUpperCase())  // map2 type is TreeMap[Int, String]
  val map3 = HashMap(1 -> "s", 2 -> "d").updatedWith(2, _.asInstanceOf[Any])  // map3 type is HashMap[Int, Any]
```

Please also note that `CanBuildFrom` pattern is much more powerfull and this example doesn't use all of it's power. Thanks to `CanBuildFrom` some operations can change the type of collection completely like `BitSet(1, 3, 5, 7) map {_.toString }` type is actually `SortedSet[String]`.

Comment: Why tie `RichMap` to `mutable.Map`?

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles No reason. I've tested it with mutable collections, but the example is generic. I have removed mutable mentioning